# Film from 1930s(+/-) with flying cars all over New York

Tags: story-identification, movie

There's a film from the 1930s (+/- a decade.)  All I remember is that there were multiple levels of flying cars zipping around New York (I think) and that all the brands had jewish-sounding names as a tweak to the notoriously anti-semitic Henry Ford.

Comment: https://youtu.be/fugbcB-mZzw - Metropolis?

Comment: No flying cars in "Metropolis."  No jewish brand names, either.

Comment: @JRE - They sorta had flying cars. There were boxy looking planes

Comment: Those were airplanes flying through the city, not cars.  There's cars galore on the roads below, though.

Comment: Not your answer, by the first rendition of what we'd recognize as a flying car dates back to 1917 (the term "flying car" was used back in the 1800s!) as per https://www.flyingcarsandfoodpills.com/flying-cars-dawn

Comment: Did they look like cars? Did they have wheels? Have wings? No visible means of support? And I'm assuming live-action versus animation? And was it a talkie or still a silent film?

Answer (score 22):

This is probably [*Just Imagine*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0021016/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) (1930).  The description on the ["Flying Cars"](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FlyingCar) page of TVTropes says:

> In the 1930's sci-fi musical Just Imagine everyone has their own propeller-driven personal airplane with horizontal props inset in each wing so they can hover in midair, allowing their occupants to chat or burst into song. In a Take That! against the anti-semitic Henry Ford, all the car manufacturers have Jewish names.

The synopsis from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just_Imagine) mentions:

> Just Imagine is a 1930 American pre-Code science fiction musical-comedy film, directed by David Butler. The film is known for its art direction and special effects in its portrayal of New York City in an imagined 1980. Just Imagine stars El Brendel, Maureen O'Sullivan, John Garrick and Marjorie White. The "man from 1930" was played by El Brendel, an ethnic vaudeville comedian of a forgotten type: the Swedish immigrant.
>
> The film starts with a preamble showing life in 1880, where the people believed themselves the "last word in speed". It switches to 1930, with the streets crowded with automobiles and lined with electric lights and telephone wires. It then switches to 1980, where the tenement houses have morphed into 250-story buildings, connected by suspension bridges and multi-lane elevated roads.

So it's set in New York, has multi-level "roads" and flying "cars", but only TVTropes specifically mentions the Jewish names.

Comment: IMDB confirms the Jewish names of the flying cars: "Hearing that people fly "Rosenbergs" and "Goldbaums" instead of driving cars, Single-O (El Brendel) comments that someone got revenge on Henry Ford, a jab at the famed car manufacturer's well-known rabid anti-Semitism. "

Comment: Hah... funnily enough that came up during my search for 1930s flying car films, albeit with the Instant Baby clip. https://paleofuture.com/blog/2007/10/4/instant-baby-machine-1930.html

Comment: Is this the movie with the amusing song "Never Swat a Fly"? Hah. Yes, it is.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QE3-KcDzGDA